# Groupby with apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not able to figure out the error -

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'startswith' generated from the line - "year_indices = [x for x in sum_series if x.startswith("emissions")]"
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2021-03/state_tier1_caps.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(URL, sheet_name="State_Trends", header=1)

def minmaxyear(subdf):
    sum_series = subdf.sum()
    year_indices = [x for x in sum_series if x.startswith("emissions")]
    minyear = sum_series[year_indices].astype(float).idxmin()
    maxyear = sum_series[year_indices].astype(float).idxmax()
    return pd.Series({"min year": minyear[-2:], "max year": maxyear[-2:]})

df_years = df[df["Pollutant"]=="CO"].groupby("State").apply(minmaxyear)
print(df_years)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lytseeker's answer does solve the error you were getting but it returns an empty series. Meaning the lines getting the `minyear` and `maxyear` would throw an error.

This is because it iterates through the values of `sum_series` and not the indices.

So do this instead.

```
year_indices = [x for x in sum_series.index if x.startswith("emissions")]
```

After making this change I was able to get this output -

```
       min year max year
State                  
AK          07       02
AL          21       90
AR          21       90
AZ          21       90
CA          21       90
CO          16       90
CT          21       90
DC          17       90
DE          21       90
FL          17       01
GA          17       90
```

Comment: It works well as I want, thanks for your comments and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since x is an integer, in order to do a use a string function on it (`startswith`), you should first convert it to `str`:

`year_indices = [x for x in sum_series if str(x).startswith("emissions")]`

Comment: This does solve the error OP was getting but doesn't help in returning the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass mask for compare indices of `Series`:

```
def minmaxyear(subdf):
    sum_series = subdf.sum()
    year = sum_series[sum_series.index.str.startswith("emissions")].astype(float)
    minyear = year.idxmin()
    maxyear = year.idxmax()
    return pd.Series({"min year": minyear[-2:], "max year": maxyear[-2:]})

df_years = df[df["Pollutant"]=="CO"].groupby("State").apply(minmaxyear)
print(df_years.head())
      min year max year
State                  
AK          07       02
AL          21       90
AR          21       90
AZ          21       90
CA          21       90
```

Comment: The code is rewritten from the original one and it works correctly, thanks for your great idea.